# Can the word 'in' be used to show equality?

Tags: word-meaning

Take these two sentences:


**1. You're supposed to drink up to your body weight in grams of water.**


**2. The average woman uses her height in lipstick every 5 years**


I can understand that in the first, you're supposed to drink as much water(in grams) as your weight,


 *i.e. if your weight is 120lbs, drink 120 grams*


And in the second if the person's height is 169cm, then they use that much lipstick every 5 years.


But I haven't found a definition for this kind of usage. So I was wondering is the word 'in' meant to show equality or correlation?

I'm pretty sure that it is, but would like some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition **in** serves to introduce the measure - unit, scale, instrument or system used to judge the weight (or height) concerned.

The unit could as easily be from the imperial system (pounds and ounces - feet and inches) or any other object whose size and weight are well understood.

One can estimate people's weight in carob seeds or their height in lego blocks. **In** simply introduces the item or scale used.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence does not actually say what you say that it means. Should it read as follows?

> You are supposed to drink as much water in grams as your body weight in pounds

"in" is commonly used to define the units of measurement that are relevant. So : ...water in grams...; weight in pounds; temperature in Fahrenheit; how much is that in dollars? - and so forth.

But when you are actually measuring something then 'of' is used:
add three ounces of salt; heat to a temperature of 35 degrees; 120 grams of drinking water, please.